# Link build configuration to a publish profile

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why does Microsoft not allow you to link a build configuration to a publish profile.  Instead it tells you to use the dropdown in the main VS interface.

[image: Publish Dialog]

I find this extremely annoying, because we use config transforms to change our config settings based on the environment we are publishing to (such as database connection strings).  We also check-in the .Publish.xml file, so that the publish paths are saved in source control.  If someone forgets to change the build configuration they could accidentally publish test to production or vice versa.  If we could check in the build configuration selection with the publish profile we would not have this issue.

Does anyone know if Microsoft plans on changing this in the future?

Comment: I don't know if they plan on changing it, but you could [open a ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and let people vote it.

Comment: +1 to this. Seems like such an obvious flaw and such an easy fix...

Answer (score 6):

By pure luck, I found this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/06/15/visual-studio-2010-web-publish-updates.aspx

If you install this update (related to Azure), then the publishing tools are updated to a wizard type interface that DOES tie a publish profile to a specific build configuration.

I don't really understand why this is tied to Azure, but it works perfectly for all types of publishing (I use the publish to a folder option).  No more publishing with the wrong build configuration!

Comment: Man - thanks a ton for taking time to publish this - definitely the BEST solution for the problem!

Answer (score 2):

To get around this, you can write a batch script to do both parts of the process.  Use MSBuild to build your projects in the required build configuration (we use release for our web apps).  If all you need to do is copy the output, MSBuild should be able to do that for you as well with a copy task.  If you need to deploy a web application, use MSDeploy command line tools to complete the publish command.  Going command line with both of these tools opens up a lot of customization.

Comment: This is not a bad idea and I would also recommend going just a step further and implementing CruiseControl.NET. I've actually just done this for our project and we have an incredibly comprehensive build targeting system.... it will hurt for a day or so though! (depending on how complex your build requirements are)

Answer (score 1):

I very much agree that this should be implemented. It's currently very easy to make fatal mistakes when publishing.

Seems like this will be (/has been) fixed for Visual Studio 11 but won't be changed for Visual Studio 2010:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690284/publish-profiles-do-not-include-build-configuration