# How can I ensure a project only publishes in Release configuration while still letting me debug in other configurations?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce, publish, .net-4.8

I have two .NET Framework applications, one a ClickOnce application and the other a web application, which I want to prevent from ever being published with the debug configuration.

How can I force Visual Studio to only ever publish them in the release configuration while still letting me build and debug in other configurations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restricting publish profiles can be achieved by including a build target in the **.csproj** (or **.pubxml** for web application) file for the project, as seen here.  This will not force Visual Studio to only publish in the Release build config., but it will cause a failure if it is not run in Release build config.

#### For ClickOnce WinForms Project

I encountered a weird error where a directory could not be found when I redefined the `BeforePublish` target directly, so I made this run before it using `BeforeTargets`.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
  <Target Name="ErrorWhenPublishingNotInReleaseMode" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">
    <Error Text="The application must only be published in the &quot;Release&quot; configuration." />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

#### For .NET Framework Web Application

Add the following to the .pubxml file you publish with.  The .csproj files don't seem to be used when publishing such a web application.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">
    <Error Text="The application must only be published in the &quot;Release&quot; configuration." />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Other available targets (`<Target>` Name proprety) can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019

A reference to how to use the `Condition` property of the `Target` tag can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019

I did find this other sort of relevant question, [Can I force Visual Studio to use only a Release build configuration for my production publish profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236719/can-i-force-visual-studio-to-use-only-a-release-build-configuration-for-my-produ), but the question is too specific about other requirements and the selected answer is incorrect for my question.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I would have already if I didn't have to wait a minimum of 2 days from the initial ask.  This is for other's information, given that I could not find a direct answer like this to the same question.  I wonder, though, do you have a better solution?  I am supposed to pick the best answer, not just any answer.

Comment: I think it is the best answer that I have ever seen and  that is why I vote it:) Great!